# Issue with "jsessionid" on production (https) server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using the following code in my web.xml file to prevent "jsessionid" displayed on the URL.

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

It works on my local host/staging(http), but when I deployed it to production, it still displays the jsessionid. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The code I mentioned in my question works only for Tomcat 7. Our prod servers use tomcat 6. Our server admin have resolved this issue.